# Why notifation is not getting displayed?

Tags: android

Below is my receiver that is working fine.. on receive function is getting hit ..I confirmed this by using toast . but why notification is nor working.

```
    @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            Bundle extra = intent.getExtras();
            String msg= extra.getString("message");

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message received."+ msg,
                //  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);



            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    RegisterActivity.this)
                    .setContentTitle("Notification From GCM")
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                    .setContentText(msg);
                    mNotificationManager.notify(100, mBuilder.build());


        }
    };
```

am I missing something??

Answer (score 1):

Quote from [here](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html):

> At bare minimum, a Builder object must include the following:
>
> - A small icon, set by `setSmallIcon()`
> - A title, set by `setContentTitle()`
> - Detail text, set by `setContentText()`

So I guess, you have to put an icon in your notification builder.

As you can see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#icon), a notification with an invalid icon will not be shown.

Answer (score 0):

You missed `setSmallIcon` for builder so, change your code

```
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                RegisterActivity.this)
                .setContentTitle("Notification From GCM")
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                .setContentText(msg);
```

to

```
  NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    RegisterActivity.this)
                    .setContentTitle("Notification From GCM")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                    .setContentText(msg);
```

For more info see [Implementing GCM Client](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html) and search for **sendNotification** method.

Comment: why would I need pending intent? I don't want to set any action for notification.. I just want to display notification

Comment: @Mr.Vicky try to add                     `.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)` and change `ic_stat_gcm` with your icon name.See edited answer.

Comment: @Mr.Vicky Happy to help,enjoy.